# Good way to allow users' images into resources of Android app?

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

In my application I'm showing users the items in list, with items looking like that:

[image]

Right now the objects I use to build such list have a field indicating the icon I want to use. Icons (with proper size) are stored in folders `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi`, `drawable-xxhdpi`.

```
public class ListItem {
    private String firstLineText, secondLineText;
    private String iconName;
 }
```

I keep a map binding the icon name and the resource id like that:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("icon_1", R.drawable.icon_1);
```

In my class extending ArrayAdapter, in `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method I simply take the icon from the map and put it in corresponding ImageView object (on the screen it's the green android).

However, this approach seems way too much hardcoded for me, because in the future I want my app to be customizable. My application is going to be just a client in the server-client system. I want admin of the system to be able to change or add new icons for example using a webservice.

So, what is a good way of storing images from outer world programmatically and then feeding the application with them?

Comment: On a web server or internal or external storage of the device.

Comment: Save the images/icons to internal or external memory. Then use `map.put(icon_1, "full path to icon");`. And change getView() in such a way that you check first if the second argument is a resource identifier or a full path.

Comment: @greenapps what about scaling images for different screens? Drawables are stored in a few different resolutions, is it possible to scale images saved in memory on the fly?

Comment: Yes. That is of course possible. But for one device the needed image will be the same always so you could download in the right size at once.